# How to insert new line(vbnewline) after specific word in richtextbox vb.net

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox, lastindexof

How to insert new line(vbnewline) after specific word in richtextbox vb.net
heres the ex.

```
ITEM # 1234 BLUE 100.00 ITEM # 3214 RED ITEM # 1235 GREEN 120.00 ITEM # 3514 ORANGE
```

The output should be

```
ITEM # 1234 BLUE 100.00
ITEM # 3214 RED 211.00
ITEM # 1235 GREEN 120.00
ITEM # 3514 ORANGE 543.00
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How About...

```
Dim Input as string= "ITEM # 1234 BLUE 100.00 ITEM # 3214 RED ITEM # 1235 GREEN 120.00 ITEM # 3514 ORANGE"
Dim Output as string= Input.Replace("ITEM", Environment.Newline & "ITEM" & Environment.Newline)
```

Comment: This will put a newline to the first "ITEM" also.

Comment: @Ronald Since you're the OP, I've approved your edit but can you clarify why you had to do that? The 2nd Newline would mean each `ITEM` is on a line on its own? Both for my own curiosity and to help others who end up here in future